# How to attach a file to a message?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to attach files from a directory. I have tried multiple commands.

The outlook msg is saved in the folder but without attachment and I need to attach it.

Here is a part of my code.

```vb
Dim filename, file As String
Dim folder, path As String

filename = folderpath & "\sheets\"
file = Dir(filename & x & "*.xlsx")

Dim ObjMsg As Object
 
'Create email
On Error Resume Next
Set olapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    DoEvents
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set ObjMsg = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
DoEvents
 
ObjMsg.To = ""
ObjMsg.CC = "" 
ObjMsg.Subject = ""
  
ObjMsg.BodyFormat = 3 'Set richtext format
Set editor = ObjMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor
editor.Content.Paste
wd.Quit SaveChanges:=False

While Len(file) > 0
    ObjMsg.Attachments.Add (filename & file)
    file = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: I have tried the below command as well but nothing works.

Comment: you look for `filename & x & "*.xlsx"` but attach `filename & file`. what is `x`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fso, objFiles As Object
Dim folder As folder
Dim fil As file
Dim ObjMsg As Object
Dim file As String

strPath = getFunction

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(strPath).Files

For Each fil In folder.Files
    file = strPath & "\" & ".xlsx"
    'Create email
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    DoEvents
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set ObjMsg = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    DoEvents
     
      ObjMsg.To = ""
      ObjMsg.CC = ""
      ObjMsg.Subject = ""
      
      ObjMsg.BodyFormat = 3 'Set richtext format
      Set editor = ObjMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor
      editor.Content.Paste
      wd.Quit SaveChanges:=False
      While Len(file) > 0
        ObjMsg.Attachments.Add (file)
        file = Dir
      Wend
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the code:

```
Dim objFolder, objShell
On Error Resume Next
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "select the folder where the files are located " ,0)
If IsObject(objFolder) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
```